# Selected button during Home Screen

Tags: android

I have a home screen with a Home button.   This screen is the default screen when my application starts up.   I would like to show the Home button as selected to indicate that the user is in the Home screen when my app starts.   How do I do that?  Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the Home button an image button or a regular button?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you find a response is helpful, please up vote it. If the response successfully answers your question, please click the check mark next to it to accept the answer. Also please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for advice on how to write a good question

Answer (score 0):

I think for what you want to do you want to either use a group of [RadioButtons](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html#RadioButtons), or [tabs](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html). If you just want a button that looks different in different states, try using a [StateSelector](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList).

Comment: Thanks but radio button and tabs can't accomplish what I wanted it today.  radio button is either on or off.   my home button has multiple states.   during the home mode,  i want it to be shown selected.